# Cancel one day of a regularly scheduled notification in Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a notification that users receive daily. It's supposed to be a reminder. However, users need to skip notifications ocasionally,

I am triggering these expo notifications using

```
Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
            content: {
                title,
                body,
                data,
                categoryIdentifier,
            },
            trigger: {
                channelId,
                hour: reminderTime.getHours(),
                minute: reminderTime.getMinutes(),
                repeats: true,
            }
        })
```

Is there a way to disable the notification temporarily say for a day? Right Now I am just deleting the channel and resetting it after that day. But I am assuming there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you create an exception list and validate before sending the notification.

```js
exception = "01/07/2022"

if (new Date() == new Date(exception)){
    return console.log("[NOTIFICATIONS] - exception found")
}

// normal post
```

Comment: There is no date. it repeats every day. at certain time